# Form validation javascript - check input values

Tags: javascript, validation

I’m trying to validate all the inputs from a form using the same function for every input value.
The form should submit if the inputs aren’t empty.
The function **validateInputs()** should return true only if the inputs aren’t empty but somehow returns true all the time so the form will submit with the empty inputs.

```js
 addBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (
        validateInputs([firstName, otherNames, street, town, country]) &&
        validateEmail() &&
        validatePhone()
    ) {
        id++;
        //creating a new contact object
        const contact = new Contact(id, firstName.value, otherNames.value, emailAddress.value, number.value, street.value, town.value, country.value);

        //push to the array
        ContactArray.push(contact);

        //Storing contact record in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(ContactArray));

        //Clear input fields after submit
        clearInputFields();
        //Adding to list
        addToList(contact);
        //success message
        setMessage();
    }
});

const validateInputs = (inputArr) => {
    inputArr.forEach(input => {
        // check if is empty
        if (checkIfEmpty(input)) return;
        if (!checkIfOnlyLetters(input)) return;
        return true
    })
}


function checkIfEmpty(field) {
    console.log(field.name)
    if (isEmpty(field.value.trim())) {
        // set field invalid
        setInvalid(field, `${field.name} must not be empty`);
        return true;
    } else {
        // set field valid
        setValid(field);
        return false;
    }
}

function isEmpty(value) {
    if (value === '') return true;
    return false;
}
function setInvalid(field, message) {
    field.className = 'invalid';
    field.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = message;
    field.nextElementSibling.style.color = error;
    field.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
}
function setValid(field) {
    field.className = 'valid';
    field.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = '';
    //field.nextElementSibling.style.color = green;
}
function clearAll(fields) {
    fields.forEach(function (field) {
        // check if is empty
        field.className = "clear";
        field.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = '';
    })

}

//check if contains only letters
function checkIfOnlyLetters(field) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(field.value)) {
        setValid(field);
        return true;
    } else {
        setInvalid(field, `${field.name} must contain only letters`);
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-form">
          <form id="form">

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="First name" id="firstName" />
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="otherNames">Other names</label>
                <input type="text" name="Other names" id="otherNames" />
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="emailAddress">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" name="Email address" id="emailAddress" onfocusout="validateEmail()"/>
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="contact-num">Phone number</label>
                <input type="text" name="Phone number" id="contact-num" onfocusout="validatePhone()" />
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="street">Street</label>
                <input type="text" name="Street" id="street" />
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="town">Town</label>
                <input type="text" name="Town" id="town" />
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                <input type="text" name="Country" id="country" />
                <small>Error Message</small>
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code (the HTML and the declarations of your `validateInputs` array items.

Comment: Actually, with this code, the `validateInputs` function is not returning anything, *i.e. returning undefined*, the return statements are in the function that's passed to `.forEach`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the `validateInputs` function:

```js
const validateInputs = (inputArr) => {
    inputArr.forEach(input => {
        // check if is empty
        if (checkIfEmpty(input)) return;
        if (!checkIfOnlyLetters(input)) return;
        return true
    })
}
```

There are two issues with it:

1. The function is not returning any value, despite it being used in an if statement.
2. The forEach method does not return anything either - [see its' documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value). It is used to iterate over an array in a functional syntax (similar to a for...of loop.

If your goal is for the function to "return true only if the inputs aren’t empty", you need to check a condition for every input and run an "&&" for all inputs. The best way I know to do this for an input array is the ["every" method for Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

In your case, I would rewrite the function in the following manner:

```js
const validateInputs = (inputArr) =>
    inputArr.every(input => !checkIfEmpty(input) && checkIfOnlyLetters(input));
```

Note that by removing the braces ("{" and "}") from the function I am returning it's value directly (which I imagine was your intension) using the arrow function syntax. If you prefer braces:

```js
const validateInputs = (inputArr) => {
    return inputArr.every(input => !checkIfEmpty(input) && checkIfOnlyLetters(input));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the method validateInputs is not returning anything
because you are returning on the callback function not on the original functional itself, instead you can use every to make sure all array elements follow the same rules you set

```
const validateInputs = (inputArr) => {
    return inputArr.every(input => {
        // check if is empty
        if (checkIfEmpty(input)) return false;
        if (!checkIfOnlyLetters(input)) return false;
        return true;
    })
}
```